# MVC Code Reuse Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to learn MVC. I have created an action method which basically populates information on a social network wall. This is going to need to be used in many different actions.

Is there anywhere in mvc i can create a method to be called by any action in any controller? Where is it and what is it called please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669685/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669685/is-there-any-application-controller-for-net-mvc-like-ruby-on-rails)

> Controller is an abstract (not partial) class so you'll want to create a base controller class that extends Controller and have your controllers inherit from it.

Then the methods you put in that base controller will be accessible by all of your controllers.